# Redmi Note 8 Pro device dead after TWRP failed

Tags: android, adb

I have a redmi note 8 pro, I unlocked the device then installed TWRP and then tried to sideload pixel experience plus, it went upto 47% and then exited with an error code on the terminal screen.

Now the phone is dead, even when I press and hold the power button nothing happens. Only when I plug in the charger the LED next to the camera comes on and the PC makes a sound confirming something is connected.

Thank you in advance, any help or advice would be much appreciated, though I am almost certain the device is as dead as it can be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so was able to fix it using UFI Box and writing a Stock ROM onto the EMMC for anyone else who will face the same problem.